# .Ajax() call not always working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So currently I have a page and if someone clicks "continue" then my javascript makes an Ajax call to the base controller to update the breadcrumb index to style the breadcrumb. The problem is that this ajax call is not made all the time. It seems completely random: could work 6 times in a row and then sometimes  not work at all. By work I mean making the ajax call to base controller to update the breadcrumb index.

This is the code I have when you click the continue button.

```
$("#submitButton").click(function () {
    updateIndex();
});
```

This is the function:

```
function updateIndex() {
var PositionIndex = 5;

if (!($("#submitButton").attr("name") == "BreadCrumb") && !($("#submitButton").attr("name") == "BackButton")) {
    $("#bc_6").removeClass("enabled").addClass("a");
    $("#bc_7").removeClass("enabled").addClass("a");
    $("#navbar").css('background-color', '#fcfcfc');
    $.ajax({
        url: "BuildingCoverages/UpdateFurthestBreadcrumb",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            index: PositionIndex
        }
    });
}
```

}

Let me know if there is any additional information you guys need!

Comment: are you checking the console to see what errors you're getting when it doesn't work?

Comment: well you do not cancel the original event.

Comment: Is the form submitting after you call updateIndex?

Comment: what do you mean by not being made? not being made at all? not returning what it should? nothing happening?

Comment: maybe cache issue.. are you checking in IE? just add random number in url for avoiding cache issue.. url: "BuildingCoverages/UpdateFurthestBreadcrumb?rnd="+Math.random()

Comment: @Asik Post does not cache.

Comment: I think your problem is on the other file you haven't included, the one receiving the ajax call.

Comment: Yes, the form submits and everything works fine but it never makes the Ajax call to the base controller which updates the index. Meaning, it should be updating the breadcrumb index to 5 (position index) but it is 4 when it goes to the breadcrumb filter which styles the breadcrumbs.

Comment: perhaps checking the .done() and .fail() events as part of your call - i.e.  `.done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})`

Comment: It is a race condition!!! You can not make an Ajax call and expect it to make it to the server with the form submission! The submit does NOT wait for the Ajax call.

Comment: You aren't giving the ajax request enough time to complete before allowing the form to submit.

Answer (score 1):

wait for the ajax to succeed then submit:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var PositionIndex = 5;

if (!($("#submitButton").attr("name") == "BreadCrumb") && !($("#submitButton").attr("name") == "BackButton")) {
    $("#bc_6").removeClass("enabled").addClass("a");
    $("#bc_7").removeClass("enabled").addClass("a");
    $("#navbar").css('background-color', '#fcfcfc');
    $.ajax({
        url: "BuildingCoverages/UpdateFurthestBreadcrumb",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            index: PositionIndex
        },
        success: function(data) {
            //do your submit here. this will wait til after ajax call is complete and succeeds.
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Just to add, make sure you do the submit using: `$("#formid")[0].submit()` to avoid re-triggering any submit handlers.

Comment: I'm still getting issues @Kevin B even with that direct submit. I used the formID with both the index and without and it still causes issues.